# Task processing in python

Tags: python, rabbitmq, python-multiprocessing, job-scheduling

I need a help on technology choice for the following problem:

There are data files coming to the system to process. Some of them are self contained (*.a) and can be processed immediately and some (*.b) need to wait for more files to get a full set. I'm loading everything that arrives at the system to a DB assigning package ids and I can send a message on the MQ.

What I need here is a component that connects to that queue and listens to those messages. When it receives a message that file arrived it needs to do more or less:

If a file name is taskA.a then create a request to workerA.
If a file name is taskB.a then create a request to workerB.
If a file name is taskA.b and we got taskA.c before than send a request to workerA with both ids.

Which technology should I use. There are a few like Celery just its hard to find the proper one by just reading docs.

Comment: Please show some initial work you've done towards this goal.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I cannot publish any code I do for my employer. There is no more beyound loading a file to the DB assigning an id and sending message that the load took place.

Comment: Then I suggest creating a simple example that doesn't look like the proprietary code or data.